# Remove commit for good

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I know there are thousands of threads for this question.

But I found out something really weird.

If you create a project on GitHub, do some commits.
Let's say commit 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
Later, you realize you want to change something into commit 3.

As you were working in your own branch, no problem to rewrite history.

So let's do this: (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549/2398593) stackoverflow answer)

```
git rebase --interactive 'bbc643cd^'

// Modify 'pick' to 'edit' into interactive prompt and :
git commit --all --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
git push -f
```

Great! The mistake is corrected. 
The history has been rewritten, so the commit `bbc643cd` is now `lkqjfhchc`.
You can check the source on your GitHub and everything will have been updated.

**But someone can still find it on GitHub!**

Access the URL: https://github.com/your-nickname/your-project/commit/bbc643cd... (full commit hash) and you will find it!

How could we remove this commit for good?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the original commit is not a part of any other branch as well?

Comment: No. I just made one commit into master to start the repo. Then I created a "dev" branch. It's only in dev.

Comment: If that can help, I noticed that not because I went to the url of the commit, but because I referenced an issue into the commit (with key word "closes"  followed by the issue id). Now in the issue I have some text saying that a commit has a reference on it, and another similar message with the new commit hash. If I click on the old hash I can see the whole commit.

Comment: It will probably disappear in a little while as long as it's not referenced by the history of any branches or tags, probably the next time github does a `git gc` on your repo and/or clears some cache of theirs.

Comment: Oh, well, mentioning the SHA in an issue comment may very well count as a reference.

Comment: @hobbs I read some posts about commits not in history. They should be cleaned 90 days later. As you said, I already did a git gc but nothing changed.

Comment: Seriously why people put -1 on this post without explanation ? Anyway...

Comment: @hobbs damn, is there anything I can do to remove this reference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted Github staff from here : https://github.com/contact

Here's the answer (I couldn't do anything about it, no prune, no gc, etc)

> Hey Maxime,
>
> The commit was available because commits are not automatically deleted
> when they're removed from the history of a branch -- they're deleted
> when they're garbage collected. I just ran garbage collection for that
> repository manually and the commit should now return a 404.
>
> > How often does the garbage collector run on your end?
>
> GitHub doesn't have a scheduled garbage collection process. We don't
> clear repository caches automatically (we're in the version control
> business, so we don't delete data unless we absolutely have to ) so
> usually, the only reason we would do that is if we had someone [writing
> in to us asking for us to clear them as part of the sensitive data
> removal process](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#fully-removing-the-data-from-github).
>
> It's also possible we might clear the cache for technical reasons if
> the content or structure of the repo was causing us difficulties to
> host it, but that would usually only happen if the repo was
> exceptionally large or had a wildly structured folder layout.
>
> Please let me know if you have any questions about this or anything
> else.
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Cheers, XXXXX

So you just have to wait or contact staff to force garbage collector in case you have the same problem !

Comment: How often do contact staff ran the garbage collector? Can I manually force garbage collector to run in GitHub?

Comment: You can't and as far as I remember they told me every 90 days but unsure. If you need to, contact github

Comment: Its not helpful to get contact with them whenever we want to clean our previous commits.  They should give as freedom to do it

Comment: I don't make the rules and I'm not saying it's cool. Just letting you know how to achieve it as of today

Comment: Should we get contact with GitHuh through https://support.github.com/contact?tags=rr-remove-data ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your additional comments :

You did everything as it should be.
The point is this: git never lose data unless you tell it to (whats known as `gc` - garbadge collector)

The files will remain there until they will gc will be called.

This is called `dangling file`

> #### Dangling commit
>
> A commit that isn't linked to any branch or tag either directly or by any of its ascendants.

You can see all the dangling references locally with this:

```
git fsck --full
```

[image]

The only way to get rid of it is to run gc

```
## !!!Caution:
## It will remove all your dangling files
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572728/lost-all-my-staged-but-uncommited-modifications-after-git-revert-abort-command/34572818#34572818) you can read some more about it.

Comment: yes and in order to clean remote as well: git push origin --force --all or something like that ?

Comment: github auto clean it once in as while. should be no more the 90 days according to their documentation.

Comment: so OP will have to wait a while to see his commit disapear on github if he doesn't do that as well

Comment: @codeWizard thanks for your answer ! When i run `git fsck --full` it checks the objects --> 100% : 91/91 done. But i do not have any dangling ...

Comment: Its only locally !!! not what github stores, just wanted to explain to you what is a dangling object so you will know what is it.

Comment: In order to remove the "original" reference you have to run this on the remote github repository (something you dont have access to) so simply wait and check it once in a while.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't understand ! I sent an email to github team, if they give me an answer I'll post it here !

Comment: I was just trying to explain it all in details as much as i can to provide full answer with the maximum details as i can.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but still, my problem is not solved. I want to wait a little more before accepting your answer :)

Comment: Appropriated, Thank you