# How to remove commit in github

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I already delete the commit from all branch, but I can still find the commit tree in github.

e.g.: the commit hash is `37b864ce1b60aa426f03ffd0b3e6e010ef5f194d`, I cannot find this commit in any branch. but I can still find the tree with that commit from `https://github.com/<user-name>/<project-name>/tree/37b864ce1b`.

How can I delete this commit from github?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove commit for good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582480/remove-commit-for-good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you upload it to your repository, those overwritten confirmations should disappear

```
 git push --force
```

Comment: That's great! I can use this method to revert B C and D in case I need to. But if one of my commit contain some personal information (e.g.: birthday, id-number). how can I delete it permanently. I don't want anyone to find this commit in github.

Comment: when I use `git push --force` it did disappear from branch. but I can still find the commit from `https://github.com/<user-name>/<project-name>/tree/<commit-number>`

Comment: I just create an example. Here is my repo: `https://github.com/b232wang/removeCommit/`.  I cannot find any commit in master, but the commit can find from `https://github.com/b232wang/removeCommit/tree/97cd611cab`

Comment: @BoyuanWang In that case you should contact the git support

Comment: git reset --hard 37b864ce1b60aa426f03ffd0b3e6e010ef5f194d

Comment: yep, I guess I need to contact the git support, but thanks anyway~

Comment: `git push --force` does not help to remove commit from GitHub