# Files committed do not appear after git commit, git stash, and git stash pop

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control

I'm very new to this git thing, and as far as my experience goes, I've never encountered something like this before.

I've multiple local branches that I frequently switch around with, since I work with a group, and use other branches as a reference.

In this case, one of my friends committed and pushed something to his branch, and he suggested we have a look-see.

So I committed my changes on my own branch, but as usual, there are those Xcode files that magically edit themselves whenever we just open them, so I thought it would be a good idea to just `git stash` them (after the commit) and deal with them later, just so I can checkout my friend's branch and fetch the update.

After that was done, I switched back to my branch, and did `git stash pop`, and checked-out said files that aren't really important.

Then I noticed the files I created are gone.

I tried to do a `git revert` but it did nothing, not that I understood what happened, anyway.

Here's the list of commands I put in:

```
git add Integra-Geochemistry/Controllers/WaterSamplingFormOneViewController.swift
git add Integra-Geochemistry/Views/WaterSamplingFormOneView.swift
git add Integra-Geochemistry/Xibs/WaterSamplingFormOne.xib
git status
git commit -m "Initial commit - added WaterSamplingForm"
git status
git branch
git branch dev/surface-thermal-sampling
git checout dev/surface-thermal-sampling
git checkout dev/surface-thermal-sampling
git stash
git status
git checkout dev/surface-thermal-sampling
git pull origin dev/surface-thermal-sampling
git branch
git status
git branch
git checkout dev/watersampling
git status
git stash pop
git checkout Integra-Geochemistry/Xibs/AddRadonFormView.xib
git checkout Integra-Geochemistry/Xibs/RadonReadingFormFourView.xib
git checkout Integra-Geochemistry/Xibs/RadonReadingFormThreeView.xib
git checkout Integra-Geochemistry/Xibs/RadonReadingFormTwoView.xib
git checkout Integra-Geochemistry/Xibs/RadonReadingFormView.xib
git log
git revert 63947089d3479fff91ae4fb2ba5d59bd39d0c30d
```

For reference, here's the log file (after I did the git revert)

```
commit 8f5a3b8a4db5bad0a750ba08cd2d5b6a8a2fe18e
Author: <-------->
Date:   Tue Jan 5 17:28:19 2016 +0800

    Revert "Initial commit - added WaterSamplingForm"

    This reverts commit 63947089d3479fff91ae4fb2ba5d59bd39d0c30d.

commit 63947089d3479fff91ae4fb2ba5d59bd39d0c30d
Author: <-------->
Date:   Tue Jan 5 17:13:35 2016 +0800

    Initial commit - added WaterSamplingForm
```

I've done a lot of committing, pushing and switching branches, but I never had anything disappear on me like this.

Is there any chance my files are okay and recoverable? I'd hate to start over. Thanks.

Comment: related Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-forward/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance my files are okay and recoverable? I'd hate to start over. Thanks.

Yep.

type `git reflog` and checkout the desired commit that you want to get back to.

> Basically every action you perform inside of Git where data is stored, you can find it inside of the reflog.
>
> Git tries really hard not to lose your data, so if for some reason you think it has, chances are you can dig it out using git reflog.
>
> What this means is that you can use it as a safety net: you shouldn’t be worried that a merge, rebase, or some other action will destroy your work since you can find it again using this command.
>
> [image]

Read more about it [here](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The files I made still don't show up in Xcode, nor are they in their respective directories, though. I checked the other branches, they're not their, either (log stops at the point before "Initial commit - added WaterSamplingForm").

Comment: As a good practice, don't use stash use branches instead. If yu have not committed your files and you might want to try recover them using fsck.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572728/lost-all-my-staged-but-uncommited-modifications-after-git-revert-abort-command/34572818#34572818

Comment: I did commit the files ("Initial commit - added WaterSamplingForm"), I just didn't want to go through checking out or ignoring files that I didn't need (for some reason, viewing a xib in Xcode means you make changes to it or something). I tried fsck, but they still won't show up.