# C: Recover lost commit in git

Tags: git, github, terminal, git-commit

I was trying to commit some changes to my secondary branch in my git repository. But when I committed, I lost all my changes. My repository is now like when I first cloned it (I cloned it from my prof's repository for an assignment) and lost all my work ! Is there a way to get back those changes? I can't use reflog because my last commit was a very long time ago.
See the pictures [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqSa6.png)[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDua9.png)

Comment: What about `git checkout -` to switch to last commit you did (`secondary` branch)? then push to remote branch by `git push origin secondary`

Comment: I hope this answer will help you (if you staged the files, otherwise it is lost :-() https://stackoverflow.com/a/11096537/717372

Comment: So I woke up this morning and somehow all my files were back. I took screenshots then they disappeared again wtf? At least now I can just retype everything.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to your `secondary` branch:

```
$ git checkout seconday  # now current branch is 'seconday'
$ git log                # see the commit history
```

`Add` the untracked file, do `Commit`, then `Push` to remote `seconday`:

```
$ git add -A                 # add the untracked files
$ git commit -m 'Message'    # staged the changes

$ git push origin secondary  # push to remote 'secondary'
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps ? Because in my secondary branch on github I still don't have the changes

Comment: So turns out that my changes were present in my secondary branch but I used that wrong "push" syntax so they didn't show on github. This answer helped ! Thank you

Comment: Yes, needs  `git push origin secondary` to update remote. welcome!