# Can I recover staged changes after checkout?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-stage

Recently, I staged many changes in over 100 files. Then, unfortunately, I did a checkout of a previous commit. After the checkout all my changes are gone and not visible anymore (I'm using Fork to work with git). Are my changes really lost or can I recover the changes anyhow?

Please help!

Comment: If you really didn't commit or stash, then yes, your work may be lost.  If your editor or IDE supports a local history, then you might be able to recover the work there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thx for your answer. It's so strange because I didn't got any warning.

Comment: ...and that's the worst possible outcome.  At least if you had been warned that your changes would be dumped, it would have been on you.

Comment: What was the command you used? Git doesn't generally allow a checkout if unstaged changes are to be overwritten.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was working in VSCode and staged all changes (using the GitLens extension). Next I double clicked on a commit and this commit was checked out (no message or warning). The previously staged changes are not shown anymore.

Comment: @Lars that sucks. I think git itself would have warned you if the command line has been used. I don't know of any GUI which does?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thx for your condolence :-( I should start using git with the cli...

Comment: Given that you're not using the Git CLI, all bets may be off here. However, if the files were `git add`-ed in Git-CLI terms, the *data* for each file is in Git. *Finding* that data is the tricky part. You can find *dangling blobs* using `git fsck`; adding `--lost-found` to the command line makes Git copy the data out to files named by hash IDs, in `.git/lost-found/other/`. Figuring out which dangling blob data file corresponded to which original file is *hard*. Often it's so hard as to be pointless: it's easier just to reconstruct the files by hand. But it might help.

Comment: I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853981/717372) how to recover staged files. Other answers are also interesting. But are you sure your changes have not been stashed?

Comment: @Philippe your solution seems to work well, but is it also possible to limit the the "lost-found" creation via a timestamp, e.g. show 'lost-found' between two dates?

Comment: As it is based on `git fsck` that does not provide this type of option, no it's not possible by default. You could still convert the command in a real shell script and try to do it by accessing directly the date of the files in the '.git' objects folder. But it will be more difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I was working in VSCode and staged all changes (using the GitLens extension).
> Next I double clicked on a commit and this commit was checked out (no message or warning).
>
> The previously staged changes are not shown anymore

That last part needs to be verified in command-line, outside of VSCode.

```
git status
git stash list
```

If not, as commented by Philippe, [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) can somewhat help.

But check first what extension you are using: a double-click on a commit history should not switch to it directly, unless your VSCode+Git Lens also uses the [Git Graph extension](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph).
That extension includes [issue 39](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph/issues/39): "On double click - Checkout branch", which seems close to what you have experienced.

Comment: I re-checked and it's the Git Graph extension and exactly your linked issue 39.

Comment: @Lars That would be the origin of your problem, then. If possible, don't use that extension for now.