# Recover files from new, uncommitted git repository

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted all files from a new git repository. There are no other backups and everything is local. I did the following:

```
git init
git add .
git rm . -rf
```

I did not do an initial commit. I have tried `git checkout .` and `git reset` but this did nothing. I am pretty sure these files are gone, but please let me know if there is a way to recover them.

Comment: Some better answers in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094968/in-git-how-can-i-recover-a-staged-file-that-was-reverted-prior-to-committing

Comment: Thank you, it works great!