# Restore accidentally removed untracked files in git

Tags: git

I've accidentally removed my new files (never been committed) on git that were untracked (I forgot to stage and commit them). Is there any way for me to recover them?
PS: I've checked Visual studio local file history. Unfortunately, I couldn't find them. Also, I have used some hard recovery software but nothing happened.

Comment: Untracked files are, by definition, not *in* Git. This means they cannot be recovered *by* Git.

Comment: If you ever staged the files (but didn't commit them), then you may be able to [recover the contents of the files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11094968/184546).