# How can I restore files after 'rm -rf'?

Tags: git, github

I did a git add from my VScode, then I saw there were some files I didn´t want to push so I did a `git rm -rf` to take away everything. I am a newbie (didn't expect this).

Is there a way to restore my files after this?

I m on a Mac and already tried git reset, git checkout. Any help would be great!

Comment: is it a new branch/repo with no history?

Comment: restore from trash?

Comment: don't execute command you don't understand

Comment: `git rm -rf` should generate an error similar to `fatal: No pathspec was given. Which files should I remove?`. Did you do something like `git rm -rf *`?  You might try `git reset --hard`, but make sure you understand what that does before you execute it.

Comment: If you have staged the file, git can help you retrieve the content but not the file names. There are 3 good answers (and one from me ) on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094968/in-git-how-can-i-recover-a-staged-file-that-was-reverted-prior-to-committing/58853981

Comment: Were the files committed and the commits pushed somewhere?

Comment: Hi in the end i got it fixed. My friend found this page and the command git stash and I was able to recover my lost files. To answer all your questions I didn't a prior branch and repo @eftshift0.

Comment: couldn't restore it from trash @C1sco :) all good now

Comment: nope they weren't @knittl

Comment: everyone has their own learning curve @rioV8, mines a bit bumpier than yours. hope you have a good day!

Comment: @WilliamPursell I tried the `git reset --hard` but it didn't work for me the `git stash` command did the trick for me!

Comment: if I have a bumpy ride and park my car against a concrete wall I have to live with the consequence, nobody will fix it for me.

Comment: the `f` in `-rf` means `force`, that means there is no way back, or they will add an option `-ff` meaning `are you really sure`

Comment: @rioV8, I think getting aid and feedback from outside is always a good option, to each their own, though.