# Recovering file from dangling blob

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was learning git and I had accdentally deleted unstaged files using `git clean -xdf`. I want to get them back

I tried `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog` and now I have the dangling blob of it which looks like `3x1xd7x4090xd9x350x490d8xd76743x670xd0c5`
How do I get the files back?

Comment: FYI, it's impossible to recover **unstaged** files using git object storage. If you found something interesting, it's that it has been stage. There are some interesting answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11094968/717372

Answer (score 3):

If you have a dangling blob, you can use [`show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) or [`cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) to display its contents:

```
git show 31d74090....
```

or

```
git cat-file -p 31d74090...
```

Standard shell IO redirection can be used to write a real file in your filesystem again.

Comment: @knittl I have a hunch that the comment will land in `/dev/null`