git reset head --hard deleted local files
I'm not sure where to start. I'm a beginner at git and trying to get the lay of the land.
Today I was working on a project and did not commit. My last commit was yesterday. I got on my PC and decided to commit my work before continuing as I work from 2 different PCs.
The commit got stuck midway. From the documentation I've seen a reset head --hard would fix the issues. (In hindsight this was a terrible idea.) When I did the reset it went back to the last head and my current changes were not committed to GitHub. I lost a couple new files and some work done on existing ones.
By the way, the commit was actually successful right AFTER the head reset and it sent a commit to GitHub with the rolled back files.
I tried a couple things
git fsck --lost-found

it returned 1 dangling tree blob which I ran through
git show 8474d5166d62918b3318fe1275029c10049d5b8b

which returned this
admin.mydomain.ca/
assets/
cx.domain.ca/
index.html

I checked trash and .git folder under my repo with no avail.
The last thing I've got is this file from the original commit attempt that hung up and was hit by my git reset --hard. Which is the original correct files that were lost/rolled back.
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch main
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   admin.mydomain.ca/assets/css/dashboard.css
#   new file:   admin.mydomain.ca/assets/js/dashboard.js
#   modified:   admin.mydomain.ca/assets/php/login.php
#   new file:   admin.mydomain.ca/assets/php/logout.php
#   new file:   admin.mydomain.ca/customers.php
#   modified:   admin.mydomain.ca/index.php
#


Tried
git reflog
93d3f70 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD^
bff6257 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD^
600805b HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD^
5d31c32 (test) HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD
5d31c32 (test) HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD
5d31c32 (test) HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD
5d31c32 (test) HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD
5d31c32 (test) HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD^
cd5ba09 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to HEAD
cd5ba09 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{9}: reset: moving to cd5b
cd5ba09 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{10}: reset: moving to cd5ba09
cd5ba09 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from test to main
5d31c32 (test) HEAD@{12}: reset: moving to HEAD~
cd5ba09 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from main to test
cd5ba09 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{14}: reset: moving to HEAD
cd5ba09 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{15}: commit: Bug fix, dashboard update
5d31c32 (test) HEAD@{16}: commit: Back to normal
600805b HEAD@{17}: commit: testing
bff6257 HEAD@{18}: clone: from https://github.com/myuser/mydomain.git

I messed around with moving head see if I could find anything but nothing. cd5ba09 is the recent commit with rolled back files. And nothing from git show came out as the missing files

Pretty sure the files are gone.  Be glad you learned the lesson this way and only lost half a day of work.

This is the main reason I commit frequently. My rule of thumb is if I have been writing code for more than 5 minutes, then I stop to make 1 or more commits. I also use git stash before I do anything that might lose any work, such as git reset.

If the files has been staged, you should be able to recover the contents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853981/717372

@Code-Apprentice 5 minutes might even be on the longer side, some argue you should never be more than 2 minutes away from checking in and going home (an excellent video, well worth watching).

@hlovdal Agreed. For someone who commonly goes a whole day without commiting, I would recommend starting with like an hour or 30 minute timer and then continually shorten it until they make a habit of committing more regularly.

@hlovdal As an exercise, I've even gone as far as setting a timer for 2 minutes or so, and at the end of the timer git reset --hard HEAD. The idea is to make one or more commits that are "functional" and/or "complete" in some manner before the time is up. I've only done this for leet code and code katas type problems. I'm not brave enough to do this for production code.

I'm not sure if I should post the answer but I found a solution after a while of fiddling around and trying not to move too much stuff around. I was even running a disk drill to recover deleted files.
The solution for me was in VSCode all along. from the Explorer view, I clicked the Timeline -> More action -> Local History and was able to search and find the files that we're missing/rolled back.
VSCode was a life saver here and I had no idea it was running a background service to keep local files backed up EVERYTIME I was saving.
I might be a Git dummy but I sure do CTRL+S every line of code :)

Please stop saying GitHub. That's a web site. This is about Git.

The branch can be reset to a previous commit prior to the hard reset.
git reset --hard cd5ba09 


This won't help, because "today I was working on a project and did not commit. My last commit was yesterday."

Yeah tried the reset. It pulls back to the commit I just did which we're the rolled back files
