# Why my Git Status is hanging

Tags: git

My git status task is just hanging ,even after keeping my `git status` till 1 day it doesn't give me any result ,I just changed 2 files .
My `git branch -lvv` ,below is the result with GIT_TRACE = 1

```
19:15 ~/code/arpit/project/devl (EPIC-31608_ModifyFrontEnd)
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git status
19:15:07.232867 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git status
```

It just stops here . I did `git fsck` and `git gc` but doesn't help me with `git status` .

The `git status` task just keeps hanging . There is no other git status process running , the other thing is the `git status` runs perfect on other locations . Not sure what's wrong with this one and is there a way where I can determine what's wrong with my `git status` for this local repo .

Also to Note : output of my `git fsck`

```
19:22 ~/code/arpit/project/devl (EPIC-31608_ModifyFrontEnd)
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (4654402/4654402), done.
Checking connectivity: 4654402, done.
dangling commit f3f90543e3fc481120a5381ddad922f0a5c50276
dangling commit c19a07698268ce6a3675168f2b512595454480db
dangling commit 55b80a12843b33145acf963d07097ebf8162a929
dangling commit 65cf0c2bf22ead6164fba39967e6dbafc24c0999
dangling commit ecfa0f55a0149d5a3d8f00d0236f403b842e1285
dangling commit 106010c7cdb1ddb89c38e4fcdce5f9bc694f8cca
dangling commit bf911112f5f4b7d3b27ad7bb7feaf021e3c2628b
dangling commit f71e120e97195e1deb24e438c95de259984a1a17
dangling commit a46612e46cc1869f7b2b1707d432d31ac234c4fa
dangling commit 216b13fd2047124e5345267adce233804ba8db97
dangling commit 5c3a163a4fe0fbe4d42083ab158393343b29baea
dangling blob b343170f9ae95f0b359aae2e3bb733d00c3eb442
dangling commit dc1e18edc2506af1ddac3dc2a0078bbcfd3a939b
dangling commit ac76180c82026b4955f5280cc501d926a302f90d
dangling commit 7e591ba37c6b7bf6a9868f91195d60bd63fed002
dangling commit d4821bfda8cf53438319fef51fe5dd47f24b4458
dangling tree 9b0c1c05e38920b1d49a3d474523ae78a921866f
dangling commit 7f081ec7c80c53760db7c3c9c825926aaf811606
dangling commit 773c21d5dfa0a9a07162b3d49f013de9109501de
dangling commit c55c219befb2fb754260b17804bba4f8b649046f
dangling commit 64e726ccdce72292d78b1bd291c5af8a5283efee
dangling commit 6ab2288cec60861306460d7db8747b3e1c5bc0e4
dangling commit 8d632ed94570180d8cdc6479a2d5a265e8ea9020
dangling commit 42c42fa2dd3817b3a53ce8bbebe6e71352ba0c10
dangling commit c58230b444220e4bef58afe4df38307d33a2d597
dangling commit 1304326822e1fa324f560725b22b03f72a97e741
dangling commit 0a38329819a8be2608397cd430825cd66b63f31e
dangling commit ad48320bb705006479069151fa92c9e3fa630348
dangling commit b61034ae760935fe9b6a55f2f7362b0d9a0a281a
dangling commit f29134f02c78bf41256c15ec26671aead571c8ab
dangling commit 5eeb3543bff538881037d030fc4cadf395af4fd2
dangling commit fc2136383ccb2c6cf37fdb0438678d43fc1ec6a5
dangling blob 438c39f417effaa71bd2c7f11de7eaeac37cb245
dangling commit 683b3d4559b187b1f230b1870d6e4c39cc7541d6
dangling commit 7bbe3df8aeb569acdc38143473663bc873c6ee98
dangling commit 44894079666cd75fc74675db9adfe74c5754fc1a
dangling commit faa640494e349337525fb7534e8db4660eda4908
dangling blob 38aa4050f2397be42b5d7555ba8e2b033d16fe12
dangling commit ccd2411cca881db51b9d6d10eac553ccb5ca645a
dangling commit 795343c5fdd877425027fb6b3f0d9ba1bcca00bf
dangling commit 371c459776cbd23e546ecc962a2c9325bd36487f
dangling commit 1f0b4d6339ffb0b69c219b8163fc9a77f178390b
dangling commit 3c6b5018142bd838dfc37e8a491f297edd3b5833
dangling commit 128652241287854bfb86feaf7f05698c585cda7f
dangling commit 230e53247a8e60c8d57fbc6861345ca7be2bf0d4
dangling commit 8d7d53f715de576e63392813eea2b8805416d8b0
dangling commit 3e82549c5fbe5dbe7f96dd40359c284158cbc3c1
dangling blob e2c055e0e3654d76e3826268c5954845d6b0a627
dangling blob cc19565fd0567cc9cb267f04ceba780385e39679
dangling commit 8202584fcd83191d3c87da28c54c2201d74875df
dangling commit 7a375cc1f5adb4bffe74a18ebb16bda664cc1d36
dangling commit fbac5eae3d8f143532883d970cb832046829fcc4
dangling commit 31e85e315f42adc5c52e9dbb462d3c7474105915
dangling commit 9d3b5fd01e011dc75e8417db1be886460577ccb6
```

Comment: What happens if you try on another repo (or clone of this repo)?

Comment: How many files have you changed ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna : 2 files Changed  .

Comment: @theMayer : git status works fine on another repo or on other place . The thing is my entire workspace lies on this folder .

Comment: @arpitjoshi Could you try moving your `repo` out of the exiting `workspace` to a new `location` and trying it?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Sure I can try that ,but I am not getting why all git commands work ,it used to work 2 days back on this place ,but suddenly it has stopped working

Comment: Updated my question with git fsck output

Comment: Are you using Git-LFS? Have you mounted your work-tree on a shared folder, e.g., inside a VM image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try the same git status with the latest version of Git (2.18)

Then, since [pack files can have dangling objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955713/git-dangling-blobs), check (after doing a full backup of the repo) if a [`git gc --prune=now`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418889/6309) improve `git fsck` output, and `git status` responsiveness.