# Lost Contents of Git Stash

Tags: git, version-control

I believe I have lost the contents of my Git Stash.  Here was my workflow:

I was working on Branch A, made some changes, then did git stash.
I then checked out my Master branch as I needed to fetch from origin to keep my master up to date.
By mistake, I did git stash pop and git status in Master, where all the changes I made in Branch A were staged.

My critical mistake was that I did not want to include the Branch A staged changes in Master, so I checked those out.  This is because I assumed that if I go back into Branch A and did git stash pop, I would be back to the latest changes.

However, I checkout out Branch A, did git stash pop, and all my changes were not there.  Everything was back to the last commit.

I do understand that if I did not do git stash pop in Master, I should have got all the changes back in Branch A - so lesson learned.  But as a long shot, is there any way to recover from this?

I have tried:

```
git stash list
```

But no sign of the stash with my changes.  I realistically think I've lost those changes in Branch A but if there is anything I've missed I'd be grateful for any help?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git

Comment: Had a look at that.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution that I thought I would like to share.

You go back to the Branch where you mistakingly checked out the files after doing git stash pop (Master in my case).  You then do:

```
$ git fsck --unreachable
```

This gives you a list of the dangling blobs ...

```
unreachable blob 070204aa62dc0ef612f922a02d06d3....
unreachable blob 821c4ca73cb5c99f7fa5f23358e3a9....
unreachable blob b91c74fc1b5c0f8eb8ccfd1a8024c6....
```

I then did

```
git show 070204aa62dc0ef612f922a02d06d3....
```

This lets you view the content in the dangling blob, but does not give you the name of the file.  You can then write that content to a file by using the first 5 characters of the sha1

```
git show f0480 > myfile
```

This puts 'myfile' in the directory you are currently in.  Myfile at this point is a .txt which you can then copy and paste/convert to the correct MIME type (.php) in my case.

I also want to point out that I found vi's post on [recovering dangling commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git) helpful

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After you checked master branch and you did `git stash pop` there, you should again do `git stash` it would put all that changes into your stash again.

From what you wrote, I think that those changes should still be on your Branch A, since you just switched back from master to Branch A. Unless you destroyed them on master.

Comment: Yes I think I have destroyed them in master :(  This then begs the question... is there a way to recover unstaged changes (or files that you checked out) in master?

Comment: So try solution from link pasted by shirakia

Comment: Did that and a bit more research and found a solution that I've shared