# Git: What to do if accidentally skipped while rebasing?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

I am rebasing branch2 onto a newer version branch1. There were some conflicts so I made the merge and `git add`ed the conflicted file. But then instead of doing `git rebase --continue` I pressed up on my terminal and without thinking pressed enter to `git rebase --skip`. Will the conflict be successfully resolved, Or would git revert back to one of the versions due to the `--skip` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rebase code is rather tricky (and in 2.13, interactive rebase is mostly handled by the sequencer now, rather than by `git-rebase--interactive.sh`, although that's driven *from* `git-rebase--interactive.sh`).  Fortunately `--skip` is pretty straightforward, being partly handled in the top level shell script, [git-rebase.sh, here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/10c78a162fa821ee85203165b805ff46be454091/git-rebase.sh#L246-L248) and [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/10c78a162fa821ee85203165b805ff46be454091/git-rebase.sh#L386-L389).  Using `--skip` makes Git run `git reset --hard HEAD` before proceeding on to the skip action for the specific type of rebase (`am`, `interactive`, or `merge`: the first two use `git rerere clear` for interactive and merge rebases, and the last uses `git am --skip` for `am`-style non-interactive non-merge rebases).

What this means is that Git threw out your careful resolutions and went on to try to cherry-pick the *next* commit, and continue the rebase from there.

If you put a lot of work into these resolutions, you can try to recover the now-dangling blob (see [Recover dangling blobs in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9560184/1256452)—note that the accepted answer says to use `git show` on the hash IDs, which works, but if you have many to search through, it's [simpler to look in the `.git/lost-found/other` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9928789/1256452); the added merged files will be in there, mixed in with every other dangling blob remaining in your repository, which could be quite a few).  You probably want to abort or undo your rebase as well.

Note that you can save the end product, or product-so-far, of this rebase.  That may be useful if you have other good resolutions here.  Simply set a branch or tag name to point to the current `HEAD` commit before doing either:

```
git rebase --abort          # if it's still in progress, or
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD  # if it's finished now
```

to go back to the state you had before you started this whole rebase thing.  You can then refer to existing finished rebase parts using `name~<number>` to count backwards from that commit, or run `git log <name>` to find the rebase-copied commits with their resolutions, and cut and past their hash IDs.

Comment: For quick solution - check the 2 lines of code from this answer.