# Restore uncommitted work after checkout and reset

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have an issue using Git. I made some changes to my files and checked out to new branch using

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Actually I haven't committed code in old branch. I have moved to old branch and reverted changes thinking those changes are available in new branch. Is there any chance to restore the uncommitted changes in either of the branches? I tried `git reset --hard` too.

Here is my `git reflog` output

```
764d2e2 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from old_branch to new_branch
c5726a6 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from new_branch to old_branch
c5726a6 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD@{2}
c5726a6 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from old_branch to new_branch
c5726a6 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from new_branch to old_branch
c5726a6 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from old_branch to new_branch
```

Comment: Did you add those files to the index (git add)?

Comment: nope, i haven't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `git checkout`, if you did not specify `--force`, should keep changed files or fail in case they are also different between branches, so you should be able to commit them to whatever branch is current.

But you have run `git reset --hard`, and this is much worse, because it definitely discards uncommitted changes. I'm afraid it is not possible to restore them now.

If you had staged them as VonC described, you could use [search through dangling blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/) to find changed files.