# Recovering staged files after reset hard

Tags: git

After adding my files with

```
git add .
```

i threw it all away with

```
git reset --hard
```

Then i realised it was a misstake. I have not made a commit, ive only staged all the files. Ive read that its possible to find the missing staged files.

Ive tried

```
git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable  HEAD
```

and then checked in the .git/lost-found and i see a folder called other that has almost 34000 files named with sha1:s. I guess these are my files?

Can i get them back and restore my project like it was? Its not really possible to revert them one by one cause they are so many of them.

Comment: No. That scenario is recovering to a previous commit. I never commited. Only staged.

Comment: Staging saves only blobs. Do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45502615/7976758